# I'll create my own TFLITE and the Camera Detector Crash when ill run it on android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tflite

`private static final int TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE = 512;
private static final boolean TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED = false;
private static final String TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE = "model.tflite";
private static final String TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE = "file:///android_asset/LabelsX";
private static final DetectorMode MODE = DetectorMode.TF_OD_API;

```
I train my .tflite on google Collab and it is works but when i run it in android studio it can't. Please Help me. Thanks. The size of my model.tflite is 12.88mb`
`
```

Comment: This is the complete code....      https://github.com/BahaaIbrahim3024/SignLanguageTranslator.git

Comment: It would be useful if you add the crash logs here also